# ManagementEventWatcher throws ManagementException with call to Stop()

Tags: c#, .net, managementeventwatcher

I have the following piece of code that always throws an exception: The stacktrace is as follows:

```
System.Management.ManagementException: Shutting down 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.SinkForEventQuery.Cancel()
   at System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher.Stop()
   at Dell.Client.Framework.Common.RegistryMonitor.StopTreeWatcher()
```

The code that is causing it is in StopTreeWatcher().

```
private void StopTreeWatcher()
{
    if (bTreeWatcherStarted)
    {
        if (treeChangeWatcher != null)
            treeChangeWatcher.Stop();
        bTreeWatcherStarted = false;
    }
}

private void StartTreeWatcher()
{
    try
    {
        StopTreeWatcher();
        var strQuery = @"SELECT * From RegistryTreeChangeEvent WHERE Hive='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' AND RootPath='" + @regRootPath + "'";
        treeChangeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery(strQuery));
        treeChangeWatcher.Scope.Path.NamespacePath = @"root\default";
        treeChangeWatcher.EventArrived += OnTreeChangeEventArrived;
        treeChangeWatcher.Start();
        bTreeWatcherStarted = true;
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        if (throwExceptions)
            throw;
     }
 }
```

Is this because I am not disposing the ManagementEventWatcher object properly? I don't understand what the "shutting down" message means. But this happens when I initiate a system shutdown. How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ManagementEventWatcher throws this exception if you call the destructor without Stop() or Dispose().
I suppose that if you have the System.Management.ManagementException with errorCode = ShuttingDown (-2147217357), then you implement a service.
So you have to override OnShutdown() in you service, in which you will call dispose for your ManagementEventWatcher. If it is not a service, you have to catch event about system shutdown firstly and then dispose your ManagementEventWatcher.
You can also try this code for disposing the treeChangeWatcher. Use lock in multithreaded app.

```
private void StopTreeWatcher()
{
    if (bTreeWatcherStarted)
    {
        treeChangeWatcher.EventArrived -= OnTreeChangeEventArrived;
        treeChangeWatcher.Dispose();
        bTreeWatcherStarted = false;
    }
}
```